# Appropriate application of plotstyle directives

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, plotting

I am attempting to style a `Plot` in which all of the lines are Thick and I have selected the colors manually:

```
solid[t_] := -292 - 0.41 t;
liquid[t_] := -286 - 0.07 t;
gas[t_] := -242 - .189 t;
Plot[{gas[t], liquid[t], solid[t]}, {t, 0, 400}, 
 PlotStyle -> ({Thick, #} & /@ {Black, Blue, Red})]
```

The above code gives me the desired result, but I can't believe that the use of a pure mapped pure function is the best way to get these results.  Is there a less obfuscatious method to assigning some `PlotStyle` directives to all functions and then a set of directives that will apply to each function individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the directive using `BaseStyle`:

```
Plot[{gas[t], liquid[t], solid[t]}, {t, 0, 400}, 
 PlotStyle -> ({Black, Blue, Red}), BaseStyle -> Thick]
```